# Process XML in C# using external entity file

Tags: c#, xml, special-characters

I am processing an XML file (which does not contain any **dtd** or **ent** declarations) in C# that contains entities such as `&eacute;` and `&agrave;`. I receive the following exception when attempting to load an XML file...

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(record);
```

> Reference to undeclared entity
>   'eacute'.

I was able to track down the proper **ent** file [here](http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xmlcharent/0.3/iso-lat1.ent). How do I tell `XmlDocument` to use this **ent** file when loading my XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In versions of the framework prior to .Net 4 you use [`ProhibitDtd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.prohibitdtd(v=vs.100).aspx) of an XmlReaderSettings instance.

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

string DTD = @"<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ENTITY % iso-lat1 PUBLIC ""ISO 8879:1986//ENTITIES Added Latin 1//EN//XML""
    ""http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xmlcharent/0.3/iso-lat1.ent"">
    %iso-lat1;
    ]> ";

string xml = string.Concat(DTD,"<xml><txt>ren&eacute;</txt></xml>");

XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(
        UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)), settings));
```

From .Net 4.0 onward use the [`DtdProcessing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.dtdprocessing(v=vs.100).aspx) property with a value of `DtdProcessing.Parse` which you set on the XmlTextReader.

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
using (var rdr = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)))
{
    rdr.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    xd.Load(rdr);
}
```

Comment: your solution worked for me. I just needed to change settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse; to settings.ProhibitDtd = false;

Comment: Ok, great, ProhibitDtd is deprecated in v4.0

Comment: This could easily produce invalid XML so it's a naive approach. What happens if there is an XML declaration about the beginning of the XML string? If there is, your code will convert well-formed XML into something that is no longer XML.

Comment: @Nic Gibson You are absolute correct. The scenario you describe is not catered for nor for sceanrio's where more then one entity set is needed. It will in both cases break on xd.Load. If anyone is interested start a new question and I  will add some extra safe guard code to overcome the scenario Nic described

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, and not wanting to modify my XML (or DTD), I decided to create my own XmlResolver to add entities on the fly.

My implementation actually reads entities from the config file, but this should be enough to do what you're asking for.   In this example, I'm converting a right single curly quote into an apostrophe.

```
class XmlEntityResolver : XmlResolver {
    public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri,
                                     string role,
                                     Type ofObjectToReturn) 
    {
        if (absoluteUri.toString() == "-//MY PUB ID") {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
            sw.Write("<!ENTITY rsquo \"'\">");
            sw.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;
            return ms;
        }
        else {
            return base.GetEntity(absoluteUri, role, ofObjectToReturn);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you declare your XmlDocument, just set the resolver prior to load.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.XmlResolver = new XmlEntityResolver();
doc.Load(XML_FILE);
```

Answer (score 2):

`&eacute;` is not a valid XML entity by default whereas it is a valid [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) entity by default.

You would need to define `&eacute;` as a valid XML entity for XML parsing purposes.

**EDIT:**

To add a reference to your external ent file you need to do that within the XML file itself. Save the ent file to disk and place it within the same directory as the document being parsed.

```
<!ENTITY % stuff SYSTEM "iso-lat1.ent">
%stuff;
```

If you want to go a different route check out the information on [ENTITY declaration](http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/entity_declaration.shtml).

Comment: that's not strictly true. The `&eacute;` entity is defined in the HTML DTD. It isn't defined by XML itself but that doesn't make it not XML - just not defined. Good link though. Assuming only a few entities, copying them into an internal subset would be the pragmatic answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.alexatnet.com/content/reference-undefined-entity-error-xml-file), you have to reference them within the file; you cannot tell `LoadXml` to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered in 2004 itself at MSDN Article........ You can find it here.......

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.